# Worker role on azure with a database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-roles

I have a website with a db that are on azure, the website is secured by login and password and I would like to set up a local application that runs in the background and modifies the database.
my question is what service should I use so that it remains secure. and after my research I should be using Worker role but I can not put in place, how work a worker role. I can not seem to find a tutorial that could guide me on my research. Could you help me
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Both Web Roles and Worker Roles are basically scaffolding that runs in a Windows Server virtual machine. You may run your background app in either. If you run it in your Web Role, you'll be scaling both your website and your background task together (e.g. scale to 3 instances, get 3 instances of your website, running 3 instances of your background process). If you split between Web Role and Worker Role, you can scale separately (say, 3 instances of your Web Role, maybe 1 or 2 instances of your background process, possibly different VM sizes). You'll need to decide between scale flexibility and cost, since having multiple roles means more VM instances running at any given time.

For a tutorial, check out the [Windows Azure Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396). There's a hands-on lab, for Cloud Services, which runs a website plus a background task to process uploaded images.